# C++ thread throws Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFEE118284E (ucrtbase.dll)

Tags: c++, multithreading

So I'm completely new to using threads so it's probably a simple mistake. Here's the relevant code:

```
void MainWindow::ExtractAll() {
    store::Extract_Vector_Of_Packages(m_vector_of_packages, m_vect_of_extracted);
    ui.labelTest->setText("entered thread");
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButtonExtract_clicked() {
    // means extracting m_vector of packages
    // do this with a thread
    std::thread thread_extract_all(&MainWindow::ExtractAll, this); // error
    //ExtractAll(); // works fine so this is not the issue
}
```

I'm not sure why the `this` needs to be included when creating the thread, but without it the compiler rejects it. Like this the program compiles just fine, but starting the thread throws an "Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFEE118284E (ucrtbase.dll) ". I tried to call the same function without the thread and that causes no such issues. I did not forget to include thread.
Anyone know how I could try to fix this?

Comment: A thread object must be either `join()`ed or `detach()`ed before it's destructed. You allow `thread_extract_all` to go out of scope without calling either.

Comment: how would i do this? i assume i'll need detatch, right after the thread call?

Comment: If you want to call `detach` then go ahead and call it, as in `thread_extract_all.detach();`

Comment: BTW you need to pass `this` because `MainWindow::ExtractAll` is a non-static member function and `this` is usually passed implicitly. Since `std::thread` just sees your function pointer you need to pass it explicitly here.

Answer (score 0):

I created a thread from the main and forget to join the thread and this created an error **Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFE7682F61E (ucrtbase.dll)**. So must join the thread.
This worked for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).